# Power Query Formula Language - Detect type of columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In Power BI, I've got some query tables generated from imported data. All the data comes in as type 'Any', and I'm trying to automatically detect the type of the data in each column.

Some of the queries generate tables with columns based on the in-coming data - I don't know what the columns are going to be until the query runs and sets up the table (data comes from an Azure blob). As I will have quite a few tables to maintain, which columns can change (possibly new columns being added) with any data refresh, it would be unmanageable to go through all of them each time and press 'Detect Data Type' on the columns.

So I'm trying to figure out how I can do a 'Detect Data Type' in the query formula language to attach to the end of the query that generates the table columns. I've tried grabbing the first entry in a column and do Value.Type(column{0}), however this seems to come out as 'Text' for a column which has integers in it. Pressing 'Detect Data Type' does however correctly identifies the type as 'Whole Number'.

Does anyone know how to detect a column's entry types?

P.S. I'm not too worried about a column possibly holding values of different data types

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have multiple issues here. And your solution will be fragile, there's a better way.  But let's first deal with column type detection. Power Query uses the 'any' data type as it's go to data type. You can write a function that samples the rows of a column in a table does a best match data type detection then explicitly sets the data type of the column.  This is probably messy and tricky since you need to do it once per column.  This might be workable for a fixed schema but for a dynamic schema you'll run into a couple of things very quickly. First you'll need to write some crazy PQ code to list all the columns and run you function on each. This will work the first time, but might break in subsequent refreshes because data model changes are not allowed during refresh.  If you're using a tool like Power BI Desktop, you'll be able to fix things up. If you publish your report to the Power BI service, you'll just see refresh errors.

Dynamic Schemas will suffer the same data model change issue I mentioned above.

The alternate solution that you won't have problems with is using a Direct Query data source instead of using Power Query.  If you load your data into Azure SQL or a Tabular Model, the reporting layer will get the updated fields automatically so you don't have to try to work around using PQ.